# Multi Layered Drop-up Menu Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

My code below. This comes out to be a horizontal menu bar.  I want to put this in the footer; therefore, has to pop out.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav"> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Chicago Bears</a> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="">Running Backs</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Quarterbacks</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Lineman</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
}

ul li {
    position: top;
}

li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 149px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You want to make a pop "up" menu within the bootstrap framework?

Comment: what menu you want to popup? and where exactly you want ? because in footer dropdown menu behave differently, i mean if they are near to the bottom of the page.

Comment: If you have ever used Netflix ---> at the bottom of the video viewing screen, it has the "more episodes" tab; want to create something similar. So, the 80% of the page is covered with a video, and at the bottom (above the footer), users can navigate to different pages through the menu  Since, its at the bottom, it needs to pop up rather than down...

Comment: @mehtaameet can you post some screenshots? Have never used netflix.

Comment: @mehtaameet also, what do you mean by multilayered?

Answer (score 2):

Answered another question (that was deleted) about the same premise, a menu that pops "up" instead of down, here are my results for future users:

Created my own `.dropup-menu` class to not mess with the default functionality of the dropdown menu. In this class, i positioned the dropdown menu above the current menu item along with the arrow so now once the menu with a dropdown available is clicked, the menu opens upwards.

**CSS**

```
.dropup-menu {
    bottom: 100%;
    top: auto !important;
}

/* position the arrow downwards, pointing to the menu */

.navbar .dropup-menu:before {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: 7px;
    top: 100%;
}

.navbar .dropup-menu:after {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #fff;
    left: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 6px;
}

/* point the caret up*/

.up {
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
    border-top: none;
}
```

**Markup**

In order to use the class we have to include it inside the container of the dropdown menu, like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropup-menu">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/NMs4Z/2/

Comment: Thanks Andres, saved me the trouble of having to use write the same hack : ) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the OP simply ask for a way to place the *dropdown* selection above the menu bar.
 As of 2.3.1, the actual version of Bootstrap, it's already integrated and explayned in the examples!

You simply need to add the class `dropup` to the parent of your dropdown element

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button class="btn">Dropup</button>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Check the docs here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns), **Dropup Menus** the last part of the *Button Dropdown* section.